# Jquery (this)closest not working?

Tags: jquery, grid, this

Here is my issue:

I have a grid with an image being grey, on hover the image get colorize ( the image can not be setup as background image for information).

When Hover the image, a text appear, If I Hover on top of this text, the image stop to be colorize.

To fix this, I added the following Jquery:

```
  $('.hide').mouseover(function() {
    $('.hide').addClass('test');

       if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

    $('img.grayscale').addClass('oui');

}


 });

 $('.hide').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.hide').removeClass('test');
    $('img.grayscale').removeClass('oui');

 });
```

the class oui saying to colorize the image.

```
img.grayscale.oui {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Problem I'm having is,

when hover this text ( view archive), it colorize the image of all the grid ! It should colorize only the image the text is fitted with.

i tried to add the (this)closest. when addClass to only apply to the action I a clicking, but without success !!

How is this possible to do ?

you can see it live or see the full code here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNRBQX

Comment: try replacing the `$('img.grayscale').removeClass('oui');` type lines with `$(this).next('img.grayscale').removeClass('oui');` I can't seem to change stuff in the codepen as it gives me jquery error after I make any changes. Remember to do it for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` and `prev()` to select the previous element of the element your hovering on(meaning the image). I hope this will help you:

```
$(this).prev('img.grayscale').addClass('oui');
```

The edited [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbmJVE).

Comment: Im having the same issue now if i open one content ( example: click on the view archive in the first item of the 2nd row), all get colorizied instead of only the one I have clicked on... I have updated the codepend: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNRBQX I tried to add the this).prev in line 26 of the JS without sucess .. do you have nay idea ? Thanks :) :)

Comment: That's happening because you now changed a part of your HTML code. Please post another question regarding the new code.

Comment: hhmm ok I ll try to dig, n case if you want to have some fun you can see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018941/click-function-css-add-class-only-on-this-item