# click function, css add class only on this item

Tags: jquery, click, this

I have a grid with an image being grey, on hover the image get colorize (the image can not be setup as background image for information).

When Hover the image, a text appear, on `click` on this, I have a content which toggle.

Here are my two issues:

1 On toggle, only the image of the item have click should be colorize, actually they all get colorize unfortunatly. ( test on the first item of the secodn row)

I tried to use `$(this).prev` without success.

( see the code)

```
//** HERE THE TOGGLE FUNCTION **/

$('#toggle').click(function() {
$('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');
return false;
});

$('#toggle').click(function() {

$('.toggleaction').addClass('current');

       if($('.toggleaction').toggleClass('current')){

     $('.hide').toggleClass('displayon');
     $('img.grayscale').css('-webkit-filter', 'grayscale(0%)');


}


});
```

--EDIT:

got it by replacing:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
 $('.toggle').slideToggle('fast');
 return false;
 });

 $('#toggle').click(function() {

 $('.toggleaction').addClass('current');

       if($('.toggleaction').hasClass('current')){

     $('.hide').addClass('displayon');
 $('img.grayscale.oui').toggleClass('color');

 }

 });
```

2/ If I add more toggle section, on click of one, none of them appear . ..

Any help will be incredible !!!! If you have any suggestions, please let me know :)

To see the full code live:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNRBQX

---EDIT

I got the 1/ working fine, see updated codepen

Comment: I'm not seeing any text appear when I do anything and when I hover on an image, it changes color. Just the one image I hover on, which I think is what you want it to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: you should see view archive on hover of the first item of the 2nd row ??? Can you let me know if not ?

Comment: All of your images use the same class `.grayscale` and you have your toggle remove the class when clicked, so that removes it for all of them.

Comment: I got it working at the end, I have updated the code :) Just having issue now when toggling multiple item :(

Comment: What do you mean "when toggling multiple item"?

Comment: See updated codepend, if you click to the first item of the first row, of the first item of the second - both content get open